# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepare

Question is why is this a non-object. The DB is connected successfully and the table is there as well as the columns.

This is my code.

```
<?php
$config['db'] = array(
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'dbname'    => 'inb271assignment'
);

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . '; dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);

//New Data
$username = 'albert';
$password = 'ben';

$query = "INSERT INTO members (Username, Password) VALUES (:username, :password)";
$q = $conn->prepare($query);
$q->execute(array(':username' => $username,
                  ':password' => $password));

?>
```

And this line gives the error.

```
$q = $conn->prepare($query);
```

Thanks.

Comment: [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858)

Comment: var_dump or print_r $pdo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you are declaring the PDO connection object to be `$pdo` and you are using prepare on `$conn`.

```
$q = $pdo->prepare($query);
```

Comment: by the way, I think Password is only reserved in PostgreSQL